Looking for a way to search through airfoils based on Cl/Cd at a specific angle of attack
I'm working on a university project to design a wing that has a high Cl/Cd value when placed in a wind tunnel at an angle of attack of 6 degrees and a windspeed of 25m/s.
So far I've been using airfoiltools.com and looking at the Cl/Cd values at an angle of attack of 6 degrees given a Ncrit value of 9 and a Reynolds number of 200,000. After a quick search I was able to find one that I believe is quite suitable, but I was wondering if there was a better way of searching through a database of airfoils to find specific designs that meet my requirements.

Reynolds number will be $critical$ to your design parameters.  If your chord is 0.11 m think albatross.  If it is 2 million look into full scale gliders

Just a few clarifying questions:  1) is the Reynolds # you provided based on MAC or something else?  2) will the wind tunnel model wing have boundary layer trips installed or free transition?  3) what aspect ratio is the wing?  4) why 6 deg?  Thanks.

@AeroAndy I calculated the Reynolds number from the reynolds number calculator on airfoiltools.com and likely parameters for the wing section I will be building then rounded down to the nearest hundred thousand. I'm not sure about the wind tunnel specifications I'll have to look into it. The wing section is probably going to be something like 150mm chord length and 300mm long. 6 degrees was just the arbituary value we were tasked with designing for.

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/105348/66495 has some pertinet information regarding Reynolds #. At Re_c of 200k, you could have a fair amount of variability in your wind tunnel results unless you strategically apply boundary layer trips or grit.

Don't know of any slick searchable database but "Theory of Wing Sections" by Abbott & Von Doenhoff might get you in the ballpark.
